# Qt лицензирование

Tags: qt, лицензирование

Насколько я понял, чтобы не показывать исходный код программ, созданных с использованием Qt, необходимо приобрести коммерческую лицензию.

Проблема заключается в том, что Qt нельзя купить, он распространяется только по платной подписке (295$ в месяц и 79$ для стартапов).

Оk, предположим я подписался. Но вот программа уже создана и подписка мне больше уже не нужна.

Что происходит с коммерческой лицензией? Она остается или мне всю жизнь, только чтобы не показывать исходники, в фонд плутоватых разработчиков придётся отчислять?

Comment: Вроде ответ на этот вопрос даёт их FAQ, Q2.10: ***2.10. I have a perpetual Qt license, can I continue to use the product if I do not renew the license** Yes. You can continue to develop with the version you have but you won’t receive any updates nor have access to Qt support.* и Q2.3: ***2.3. What is a subscription license?** [skipped] After the subscription ends, you cannot develop with Qt any more, but the applications you created can be used*

Comment: Данный FAQ, лишь говорит об использовании средств разработки Qt и о самих программах, разработанных с их помощью. Но ни слова о правах на эти программы. Использовать продукт после того как подписка закончилась, под (L)GPL и собственной лицензией - это две большие разницы.

Comment: так не понятно, чем вам не подходит LGPL? Ей все пользуются, кто не хочет код показывать.

Comment: Возможно я не до конца разобрался, что есть LGPL, но в википедии весьма противоречиво об этом сказано. С одной стороны: "при этом отсутствует обязательное требование предоставления исходного кода собственных компонентов под копилефт лицензией". С другой (сразу после этого написано): "Необходимым условием лицензии является возможность модифицировать программное обеспечение, лицензируемое под LGPL, конечными пользователям, предоставляя им для этого исходный код".

Comment: Под LGPL вы должны предоставить возможность модификации не вашей программы а Qt. Если Qt в dll, то проблем вообще нет, кто угодно может подменить dll, а если Qt статически припаяна, то надо предоставить объектные файлы, чтобы можно было собрать с другой Qt

Comment: Проблемы с LGPL  могут возникать с некоторыми магазинами типа App Store, потому что пользователь не может в iOS так просто заменить dll